# Indirect function for worksheet names in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am wondering if there is an equivalent to the indirect function for worksheets or workbooks instead of cells.  What I mean by that is I am updating a rather large and unwieldy workbook for payroll for a company that has all sorts of people at different hourly rates working on different projects.  Each employee submits their payroll info for the month as an excel worksheet.  What I want to do is automate the aggregation of each employees hours for each particular project as much as possible.  If I could call a particular cell in a particular workbook without changing the formula every time that'd be great.

To put it another way, every month each employee submits their worksheet titled "Name Month".  I want to compile these in a workbook and automatically pull the data for a summary page that will list the bills for different projects.  I think I could do this if the indirect function could also be used for worksheets instead of just cells, but it can't.  Is their an equivalent function?

I do not know VBA.

Thanks

Comment: Indirect will work for that, assuming all the workbooks are open.

Comment: One of the things I'd like to do is change the name and the month in the master sheet and have it point to the corresponding work sheet.  So if I have a worksheet titled "Bob January" and I want to return cell F1 from that worksheet, how would I do it?

A1 = Bob 
B1 = January
C1 = A1&" "&B1
D1 = Indirect("C1&!"F1)

This is what I was thinking, but I keep getting #REF.

Comment: To reference a worksheet with a space you need to surround it in single quotes. D1 `=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & " " & B1 & "'"`)` of course you need to complete it with a `!A1` or whatever cell to actually reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For:

```
A1 = Workbook

A2 = Worksheet

A3 = Cell Reference
```

Use `=INDIRECT("[" & A1 & ".xls" & "]" & A2 & "!" & A3)`

To reference a worksheet with a space you need to surround it in single quotes ('). For:

```
A1 = Workbook

A2 = Worksheet Name 1

A3 = Worksheet Name 2

A4 = Cell Reference
```

Use `=INDIRECT("[" & A1 & ".xls" & "]" & "'" & A2 & " " & A3 & "'" & "!" & A4)`

To reference a particular range in the sheet that you do not have recorded in a cell, simply place it alongside the `!`:

Use `=INDIRECT("[" & A1 & ".xls" & "]" & "'" & A2 & " " & A3 & "'" & "!E34")`

**Note**: With [INDIRECT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151323), you must reference only *open* workbooks